# Why the name TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Presumably the "Ti" in Ti*k*Z comes from Till Tantau. If so, what does the rest of the name stand for? If not, why is the package named that way?

Comment: Ti*k*Z stands for "Ti*k*Z ist *kein* Zeichenprogramm". (I read it as "Till ist *kein* Zauberer". ;-)

Comment: @marmot But then it's not recursive anymore.

Comment: @HenriMenke Yes, that's precisely why I'm memorizing it that way, otherwise I would run out of memory very quickly! ;-)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's a [recursive acronym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_acronym) and it is explained in the manual.

[image]

(German for: Ti*k*Z is *not* a drawing program)

I guess the first letter **T** stems from **T**ill **T**antau.

---

Just in case the question comes up, PGF stands for “portable graphics format“.  From the manual as well (emphasis is mine):

[image]

Comment: But isn't it a Zeichenprogramm? At least, I'm sure that's what most people use it for

Comment: @SkeletonBow It's in the docs: »In a sense, when you use TikZ
you “program” your graphics, just as you “program” your document when you use TeX. This also explains
the name: TikZ is a recursive accronym in the tradition of “GNU is not unix” and means “TikZ ist kein
Zeichenprogramm,” which translates to “TikZ is not a drawing program,” cautioning the reader as to what
to expect.«

Comment: Pedantry: It's German for TikZ is _no_ drawing program.